# How can anonymous mobile users access my public Google+ posts?

Tags: google-plus

Let's imagine my mother gets a new laptop and a new smart phone.  My goal would be for her to be able to see my Google+ "Posts" page without having to log into Google.

From a laptop, without logging in to Google, it's easy to see people's public Google+ posts be simply navigating to their "Posts" page (i.e. https://plus.google.com/107770072576338242009/posts).

From a smart phone, however, again without logging in to Google, if you try to go directly to the same "Posts" page (https://plus.google.com/107770072576338242009/posts), you are redirected to m.google.com where you see a link to "Posts", but if you click it, you are asked to sign in with your Google account.  This is odd to me.  The posts are public; they should be anonymously viewable from a smart phone just like they are from a laptop.

A workaround for anonymous smart phone users to view Google+ "Posts" pages without logging in is to first navigate to the user's "Photos" page, such as (https://plus.google.com/photos/107770072576338242009/albums/posts) and then click the user's name (i.e. "[Philip Durbin](https://plus.google.com/107770072576338242009)]") to get their "Posts" page, but this is a kludge.  Is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem appears to be largely gone as of early 2013.

If I go to my Google+ page on a smartphone now with a browser that isn't logged in to Google, I can see posts all my posts, which is just great.

My only quibble is that after browsing to a particular post, the URL is pretty long and crazy, much longer than I would see on the desktop side. But at least you can share it and it seems to work (though it's a mobile view). It looks like this...

https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z12lgtbirte3xhjb104ccttjfsy5hnwr5qc0k?cbp=1ounrv6eftu7y&sview=27&spath=/app/basic/107770072576338242009/posts&sparm=cbp%3Dd12bt91dmtb9%26sview%3D25

... rather than the much shorter:

https://plus.google.com/107770072576338242009/posts/eiP4DRa2QhX

All in all it's a big win and I hope things stay this way. It'll be much easier to share individual posts from Google+ now no matter if you're logged in or not.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround for anonymous smart phone users to view Google+ "Posts" pages without logging in is to first navigate to the user's "Photos" page, such as [this one](https://plus.google.com/photos/107770072576338242009/albums/posts), and then click the user's name (i.e. "[Philip Durbin](https://plus.google.com/107770072576338242009)") to get their "Posts" page.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design as Google wants everyone to have an account to access even though the access circle is set as public. To our knowledge there is no work around for mobile access without login validation.

Comment: Do you have a reference for the claim that it is by design?

Comment: This is not an issue anymore, now you can share your public posts as regular links. For example, try this link and it should work - https://plus.google.com/+WentookOSHW/posts/D3Ny4f5uu9k

Answer (score 0):

http://www.pluss.es is a good way to expose your public Google+ posts to mobile users without requiring them to sign in to Google.  As of this writing, it's free to **have Plusses crawl your posts and expose them as a blog**.

Here's my Plusses account, for example:

http://www.pluss.es/107770072576338242009/

As of this writing, the following permissions are requested at signup:

> Pluss.es & Minimali.se is requesting permission to:
>
> - Know who you are on Google
>
>   - Associate you with your public Google profile
> - Perform these operations when I'm not using the application

Naturally, on Google+ itself, you can follow [Plusses](https://plus.google.com/118305487031101184556/posts).

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue anymore, now you can share your public posts as regular links. For example, try this link and it should work: https://plus.google.com/+WentookOSHW/posts/D3Ny4f5uu9k